# VB's 2-D string array to C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have to translate my ex-teammate's vb code into C# asp.net code. I found there is an Array **ls_data**, it contains lots of string array, but dim as 1-D array,

```
lf_save_data_F(ByVal IntelKind As String, ByVal FilewriteTime As String, ByVal Part As String, ByVal Lot As String, ByVal Machine As String, ByVal WorkClass As String, ByVal MeasureOrNot_Bp As Boolean, ByVal MeasureOrNot_Ltp As Boolean, ByVal value_S_co() As String, ByVal value_S_co_x() As String, ByVal value_S_co_y() As String, ByVal value_P_so() As String, ByVal value_S_so() As String, ByVal value_S_so_x() As String, ByVal value_S_so_y() As String, ByVal value_D_so() As String, ByVal value_L_so() As String, ByVal judge_S_co As String, ByVal judge_S_co_x As String, ByVal judge_S_co_y As String, ByVal judge_P_so As String, ByVal judge_S_so As String, ByVal judge_S_so_x As String, ByVal judge_S_so_y As String, ByVal judge_D_so As String, ByVal judge_L_so As String, ByVal dt_spec_S_co As DataTable, ByVal dt_spec_S_co_x As DataTable, ByVal dt_spec_S_co_y As DataTable, ByVal dt_spec_P_so As DataTable, ByVal dt_spec_S_so As DataTable, ByVal dt_spec_S_so_x As DataTable, ByVal dt_spec_S_so_y As DataTable, ByVal dt_spec_D_so As DataTable, ByVal d_spec_L_so As DataTable) As Long

Dim ls_data() As Array = {value_S_co, value_S_co_x, value_S_co_y, value_P_so, value_S_so, value_S_so_x, value_S_so_y, value_D_so, value_L_so}
```

And it will look like this in C# form

```
Array[] ls_data = {
                value_S_co,
            value_S_co_x,
            value_S_co_y,
            value_P_so,
            value_S_so,
            value_S_so_x,
            value_S_so_y,
            value_D_so,
            value_L_so
        };
```

And this is how my ex-teammate use it.

```
For li_k = 1 To ls_data(li_j - 1).Length
   ls_sql1(li_j - 1) = ls_sql1(li_j - 1) + ls_data(li_j - 1)(li_k - 1) + ","
```

, but in C# form trans it to `ls_data[li_j - 1, li_k - 1]`

It can not be compiled. Because **ls_data** is a 1-D array, how can I fix this?

Here's li_j set

```
For li_j = 1 To ls_data.Length
                If lb_insert(li_j - 1) = True Then

                    //Combine SQC data
                    ls_Str_Tester = ""
                    ls_Str_Value = ""
                    For li_k = 1 To ls_data(li_j - 1).Length
                        ls_Str_Tester = ls_Str_Tester + "Auto-SQV,"
                        ls_Str_Value = ls_Str_Value + ls_data(li_j - 1)(li_k - 1) + ","
                    Next
                    ls_Str_Tester = Mid(ls_Str_Tester, 1, Len(ls_Str_Tester) - 1)
                    ls_Str_Value = Mid(ls_Str_Value, 1, Len(ls_Str_Value) - 1)
                    li_RestCount = 20 - ls_data(li_j - 1).Length
                    For li_RestCountInt = 1 To li_RestCount
                        ls_Str_Tester = ls_Str_Tester + ","
                        ls_Str_Value = ls_Str_Value + ","
                    Next

                    //Combine SQL
                    ls_sql1(li_j - 1) = "insert into sqcresult(DeptName,Process,PartNo,Lot,machinename,ActualInputTime,InputDate,Tester,judgment,ItemNo,SpecID,SetTime2,ItemName,SpecName,Str_Color,Str_Tester,Str_Value,"
                    If Not ldt_spec(li_j - 1).Rows(0).Item("xusl") Is System.DBNull.Value Then ls_sql1(li_j - 1) = ls_sql1(li_j - 1) + "xusl,"
                    If Not ldt_spec(li_j - 1).Rows(0).Item("xlsl") Is System.DBNull.Value Then ls_sql1(li_j - 1) = ls_sql1(li_j - 1) + "xlsl,"
                    For li_k = 1 To ls_data(li_j - 1).Length
                        ls_sql1(li_j - 1) = ls_sql1(li_j - 1) + "InputResult" + Format(li_k, "0") + ","
                    Next
                    ls_sql1(li_j - 1) = Mid(ls_sql1(li_j - 1), 1, Len(ls_sql1(li_j - 1)) - 1) + ") values ('" + gs_user_dept + "','" + gs_user_process + "','" + UCase(ls_part(li_j - 1)) + "','" + UCase(Lot) + "','" + Trim(gdt_supervisor.Rows(0).Item("measure_machineno")) + "','" + Format(CDate(FilewriteTime), "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss") + "','" + Format(CDate(FilewriteTime), "yyyy/MM/dd") + "','Auto-SQV-" + gs_user_id + "','" + ls_judge(li_j - 1) + "'," + CStr(ldt_spec(li_j - 1).Rows(0).Item("itemno")) + "," + CStr(ldt_spec(li_j - 1).Rows(0).Item("specid")) + ",'" + Format(CDate(ldt_spec(li_j - 1).Rows(0).Item("settime")), "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss") + "','" + ldt_spec(li_j - 1).Rows(0).Item("itemname") + "','" + ldt_spec(li_j - 1).Rows(0).Item("specname") + "','" + ls_Str_Color + "','" + ls_Str_Tester + "','" + ls_Str_Value + "',"
                    If Not ldt_spec(li_j - 1).Rows(0).Item("xusl") Is System.DBNull.Value Then ls_sql1(li_j - 1) = ls_sql1(li_j - 1) + CStr(ldt_spec(li_j - 1).Rows(0).Item("xusl")) + ","
                    If Not ldt_spec(li_j - 1).Rows(0).Item("xlsl") Is System.DBNull.Value Then ls_sql1(li_j - 1) = ls_sql1(li_j - 1) + CStr(ldt_spec(li_j - 1).Rows(0).Item("xlsl")) + ","
                    For li_k = 1 To ls_data(li_j - 1).Length
                        ls_sql1(li_j - 1) = ls_sql1(li_j - 1) + ls_data(li_j - 1)(li_k - 1) + ","
                    Next
                    ls_sql1(li_j - 1) = Mid(ls_sql1(li_j - 1), 1, Len(ls_sql1(li_j - 1)) - 1) + ")"
                End If
```

Comment: please show also the missing code (where is li_j defined?) what happens prior to the loop with ls_sql1?

Comment: Arrays are .NET constructs. They don't differ from C# to VB.NET. Your code doesn't have a 2D array, it's an array containing raw Array objects. Essentially, it's a `Dim ls_data()() as Object` or `object[][]` in C#. Even in VB.NET it should be at least `Dim ls_data()() as String` or `string[][] ls_data` in C#.

Comment: **Dim li_j, li_k As Integer** . thanks for your reminder,  I forget it.

Comment: It looks like it's a 1 dimensional array, but `ls_data(li_j - 1)(li_k - 1)` it looks like it is accessing it's characters of each string.

Comment: [This article](https://www.dotnetperls.com/2d-vbnet) shows the syntax for different array types in VB.NET. A 2D string array is `Dim thatArray(,) As Integer`.

Comment: @ScarLetSilenece: yes, thanks, but where is li_j set? as J.vanLangen said, you are accessing a part of an string. but which value has li_j in your loop? if not initizialised it is 0

Comment: @nabuchodonossor: It's a for loop, start at 1, and end at ls_data.Length, I post more complete code.

Comment: @ScarLetSilenece: What I don´t understand is the use of 'Auto-SQV' as fieldname in the loop: If there is more than one element in the array, the insert statement would have the fieldname 'Auto-SQV' more than once ... this is not real sql .... could you please also provide some testdata for the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VB.NET code shows a jagged Object array, not a 2D array. The article [VB.NET 2D, 3D and Jagged array examples](https://www.dotnetperls.com/2d-vbnet) explains the differences.

`Array` is the base class of *all* arrays. The question's code essentially declares a jagged array of objects in a rather unusual way. The common way to declare a jagged array of objects is:

```
Dim ls_data()() As Object
```

Unless one wants to mix string and integer arrays though, a specific type should be used :

```
Dim ls_data()() As String
```

The equivalent in C# is quite similar:

```
string[][] ls_data;
```

In both cases, to retrieve an element from an inner array you have to find that array first, then extract the element. Both of the following expressions access the third element of the second nested array, in VB.NET :

```
ls_data(1)(2)
```

and C#

```
ls_data[1][2]
```

Multi-dimensional arrays in *both* languages are defined with a comma-separated list of the dimensions :

```
Dim ls_data(,) As String = New String(,) {{"ant", "aunt"},
                       {"Sam", "Samantha"},
                       {"clozapine", "quetiapine"},
                       {"flomax", "volmax"},
                       {"toradol", "tramadol"}}
```

And in C# :

```
string[,] ls_data(,) = new string[,] {{"ant", "aunt"},
                       {"Sam", "Samantha"},
                       {"clozapine", "quetiapine"},
                       {"flomax", "volmax"},
                       {"toradol", "tramadol"}};
```

Comment: use string[][] ls_data; to declare. It works, thanks a lot! I'll check out if this is exactly what I need. thanks again, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @ScarLetSilenece If an answer sorts out your problem, don't forget to click the tick next to the answer - It makes sure that the user gets reputation points and makes it easier for anyone else who has the same problem to see that your question has an accepted answer that might work for them as well. (And the person answering the question gets reputation points btw)